# WordPress permalinks not working, everything seems fine

Tags: migration, wordpress, permalinks

I have a WordPress blog I've migrated from another CMS, and I've being having a lot of problems with my permalinks structure: **lots of articles give a 404**, although they are there, somewhere, published.

The site is [www.muycomputerpro.com](http://www.muycomputerpro.com) (MCP for short), and for example an article that should be found is: http://muycomputerpro.com/Actualidad/Especiales/2009-las-grandes-crecen-en-la-bolsa

If I do a [search](http://www.muycomputerpro.com/?s=grandes+crecen+en+bolsa&x=0&y=0) on the search tool at MCP, **the result is there** (see EnlacesMCP-1.jpg)

[image]

But when I click on the link, **our 404 error page appears** (see EnlacesMCP-2.jpg)

[image]

The weird thing is, the article is published, and the permalink is the right one, as you can see on this screenshot of the WordPress CMS:

[image]

The permalink (below the title) is correct (http://www.muycomputerpro.com/Actualidad/Especiales/2009-las-grandes-crecen-en-la-bolsa/)

but it does not work. In fact, if I try to use the short link (http://www.muycomputerpro.com/?p=5023) the article does not show either.

I've accessed my WordPress DB and I've search the article to see if there is something wrong there, but from what I can tell all the fields are OK, here's a screenshot:

[image]

I really don't know what is causing this. The permalink structure should work (I'm using the "Custom permalink" plugin to preserve the old URLs that had a alphanumeric code at the end of the postname) and the permalink config on wordpress is "/%postname%/".

I really need help :(

Answer (score 0):

What does the custom permalink plugin do?

Based on your permalink config, I expect your URL to look like:

http://www.muycomputerpro.com/2009-las-grandes-crecen-en-la-bolsa/

But it seems what you're getting is:

http://www.muycomputerpro.com/actualidadespeciales2009-las-grandes-crecen-en-la-bolsa_we9erk2xxdappxe3wszfeattcoixxjqj02h-2fc-hollp0wcf4agtmew6zyefbwk/

Since all the other permalinks look to be correct, I suggest going to that post in the post editor, and editing the slug (right underneath the title). Delete all text in the slug box, then hit ok, and it should auto fill the slug correctly.

Comment: I've been "playing" with the system and I've deactivated the Custom Permalink plugin (<a href="http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-permalinks/">http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-permalinks/</a>) , and now the searches inside the blog work, but they link to that "strange" permalins. 

In this example, the friendly-nice URL should be:

<href="http://www.muycomputerpro.com/Actualidad/Especiales/2009-las-grandes-crecen-en-la-bolsa">http://www.muycomputerpro.com/Actualidad/Especiales/2009-las-grandes-crecen-en-la-bolsa</a>

But for the moment I haven't been able to solve that :(

Comment: You set a custom permalink structure to /%postname%/ in Settings->Permalinks right? That shouldn't cause Actualidad to show up anywhere, the link should be http://DOMAIN/TITLE-SLUG

Answer (score 0):

I've been "playing" with the system and I've deactivated the [Custom Permalinks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-permalinks/) plugin, and now the searches inside the blog work, but they link to that "strange" permalins.

In this example, the friendly-nice URL should be:

http://www.muycomputerpro.com/Actualidad/Especiales/2009-las-grandes-crecen-en-la-bolsa

But for the moment I haven't been able to solve that :(